# Cross-compile Firebreath plugin ARM

Tags: firebreath

I need to compile a Firebreath plugin for our ARM linux-based device. I don't see any section on the docs that mention how to specify what toolchain and compiler to use.

Anyone can give a tip on that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is no section in the docs is because as far as I know nobody has ever done it =] (and I wrote FireBreath, so it's not unlikely that I would have heard about it)

This would be a cmake problem -- look at what the prep scripts are doing, particularly prepcommon.sh, and how they use cmake. You'd need to figure out how to tell cmake to use an arm-targetting toolchain.  You also need to find out if there is anything different about the NPAPI implementation on your platform.  Keep in mind as well that NPAPI in Firefox is going away in the release planned for early March.

FireBreath2 will support FireFox and Chrome via native messaging but I have no idea what may or may not be different on ARM for that.  To do what you want to do you'll need to learn a bit more about both FireBreath and cmake.

Comment: Hello @taxilian thanks for reply. I got the build to work. It is just a matter of set the CXX and other variables properly so when the prep script run, it generate the projects using the right compiler. The compilation was also successful BUT, when the browser try to load the plugin it fail segfaulting on dlopen() here: `m_dll = ::dlopen(cFilename, flags);` The browser runtime is based on webkit (www.ekioh.com) and this code is how they start loading the plugin and unfortunately yes, they still rely on NPAPI

Comment: try to get a debugger attached and see what is going on when it segfaults is all I can suggest.  Good luck!